# Secondary tables with InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS

Tags: hibernate

Cosider

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract class A {
    @Id
    int id;

    @Column
    int a;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table
class B1 extends A {
}

@Entity
@Table
class B2 extends A {
}
```

Is it possible to have the column a in a secondary table, so there is one secondary table for A1 and another for A2?

Are there other approaches of splitting a table in Hibernate working for all sub-classes with InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are - use @SecondaryTable.(https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Multiple_tables)

Comment: It helps me to map a field in B1 / B2 to a column. I would like to keep the mapped field in A, annotate it once so it is in a separate secondary tables for B1 and B2.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to keep the mapped field in A. But you can trick: map a field in B1 / B2 to a column, define an abstract property in A and than implement it in B1 / B2 returning the mapped field.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is better to use @OneToOne relationship and move the fields to an entity

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract class B {
    @Id
    int id;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract class A {

    @Id
    int id;

    @Column 
    A a;
}

@Entity
@Table
class A1 extends A {
}

@Entity
@Table
class A2 extends A {
}

@Entity
@Table
class B1 extends A {
    @OneToOne
    A1 aFields;
}

@Entity
@Table
class B2 extends A {
    @OneToOne
    A2 aFields;
}
```